# Python lifelines: How to do a survival analysis on panel data?

Tags: python, survival, panel-data

I have panel data on companies and I'm interested in how several DVs and covariates impact the time until a company gets funded. My data (pandas Dataframe) looks something like that:

```
               DV1 ... DV5 CV1...CV12 Funding CompanyFounded
Company Period
A       1      0       0    5    4    False   False
B       1      0       0    5    6    False   False
...
A       2      0       0    5    4    False   False
B       2      3       5    5    6    False   True
...
A       45     1       2    5    4    False   True
B       45     534     42   5    6    True    True
```

Now I'd like to perform a survival analysis. I know that I could calculate averages and calculate the time to first funding using CoxPHFitter. But I did not find any model to fit panel data. Is there a workaround? I'm looking for something comparable to [STATA's stcox](https://www.stata.com/stata14/panel-data-survival/) command.

Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lifelines has support for panel data using the `CoxTimeVaryingFitter` model: https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Time%20varying%20survival%20regression.html

Comment: @ Cam.Davidson.Pilon could you maybe have a look at the following [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/471554/277429)?