# Creating Survival Dataset with Pythons lifelines using add_covariate_to_timeline creates NaN rows

Tags: python, survival, panel-data

I'd like to perform a survival analysis on how fast companies achieve a certain Event after their foundation. I have a dataframe with several static and non static covariates over a 5 years observation period. The companies are getting founded within the first 2 Years of observation. I tried to create the input data for lifelines CoxTimeVaryingFitter using to_long_format and add_covariate_to_timeline. 
Here is some example df:

```
Year id time_to_event event CV_stat1 CV_stat2 CV_dyn1 CV_dyn2 foundingyear
2010 1  2             0     1        0        3       4       2011
2011 1  2             1     1        0        5       7       2011
2012 1  2             0     1        0        3       8       2011
2013 1  2             0     1        0        6       9       2011
2014 1  2             0     1        0        8       10      2011
```

Here is my code:

```
df['Year'] = df.Year - df.foundingyear
df = df[df.Year >= 0]
df['time_to_event'] = df.time_to_event - df.foundingyear +1

base_df = df[['id','time_to_event', 'event','CV_stat1', 'CV_stat2']]

base_df = to_long_format(base_df, duration_col="time_to_event")

cv = df[['id', 'Year', 'CV_dyn1']]

surv_df = add_covariate_to_timeline(base_df, cv, duration_col="Year", id_col="id", event_col="event")
```

Unfortunately that results in several NaN rows for most of the companies, which does not make sense

```
start   CV_stat1    CV_stat2    CV_dyn1     stop    id   event
0       1           0           NaN         0       27   FALSE
0       1           0           NaN         0       27   FALSE
0       1           0           NaN         0       27   FALSE
0       1           0           NaN         1       27   FALSE
1       1           0           33,16667    2       27   FALSE
```

The event should be True for period 1 for that id. What am I doing wrong so that the NaN rows are included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is more than one problem with the design.

1. I first noticed that you have duplicate (start, stop, id) rows in the final dataframe, which should not be there. These should be unique (an subject can only pass through a time period once!).
2. This suggests your "times" are off, originally. Forget the concept of `time_to_event` - instead model the "age" of the company. So

```
Year id age event CV_stat1 CV_stat2 CV_dyn1 CV_dyn2 foundingyear
2010 1  1       0     1        0        3       4       2011
2011 1  2       1     1        0        5       7       2011
2012 1  3       0     1        0        3       8       2011
2013 1  4       0     1        0        6       9       2011
2014 1  5       0     1        0        8       10      2011
```

makes more sense (and we can drop `Year` and `foundingyear`).

3. But looking at this dataframe, we have the "event" occur in year 2, but we have observations in the years after - how can this be?
4. Finally, your original dataframe is almost already in a time-varying format (after a few edits), so you may not need to use `add_covariate_to_timeline`, which is designed to introduce a *new* column into the dataframe.

Let me know if this helps or you need more clarification!

Comment: Thank you @Cam.Dacidson.Pilon! I managed to prepare my df without `add_covariate_to_timeline` as you suggested in 4). Regarding you question in 3) the companies did not close after the event. I just use the survival analysis to measure how quickly each company achieved that event. Therefore i dropped all columns after the event accured.